# Can someone please suggest a solution for this Sql error

Tags: mysql

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Outer Join Mobile ON Plan.PlanName = Mobile.PlanName Where Mobile.PlanName IS NU' at line 3

```
Select PlanName
From Plan
full Outer Join Mobile
ON Plan.PlanName = Mobile.PlanName
Where Mobile.PlanName IS NULL;
```

Comment: mysql doesn't support [full outer joins](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html).

Answer (score 1):

You don't have FULL JOINS on MySQL, but you can emulate them.

```
SELECT * FROM plan
LEFT JOIN mobile ON plan.id = mobile.id
UNION
SELECT * FROM plan
RIGHT JOIN mobile ON plan.id = mobile.id
```

Also, you can use left join, right join, left outer join, right outer join, inner join based on your requirements.

Comment: Your final paragraph makes no sense. There is no situation where the *optional* 'OUTER' keyword could be *required*

Comment: I meant we have those joins, but we don't have a "FULL OUTER JOIN". So you can use those join based on whatever you want to do.